# WCF Exception: The reliable session was faulted

Tags: wcf

I am facing WCF exception that says,

***The remote endpoint no longer recognizes this sequence. This is most likely due to an abort on the remote endpoint. The value of wsrm:Identifier is not a known Sequence identifier. The reliable session was faulted.***

I have reliable session enabled for the service to make subsequent calls within same session.

I have tried increasing the timeouts at both ends, service and client, disabling application recycling, etc, but nothing worked.

We have a Load balancer in our hosting environment for which sticky sessions are enabled.

For reference, I am posting here the stack trace

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputQueueChannel`1.EndDequeue(IAsyncResult result, TDisposable&amp; item)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext&amp; requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;CallbackGenerator&gt;b__2(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Shutdown(Func`1 pendingExceptionGenerator)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnAbort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceChannelManager.OnAbort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.LifetimeManager.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.OnAbort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceContextManager.OnAbort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.LifetimeManager.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnAbort()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()
at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.Abort()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.StopRegisteredObjects(Boolean immediate)
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownWorkItemCallback(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Can somebody help me to sort this out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I'm not sure it's still relevant.
Anyway, here is my try.

I had the same problem/error message and I tried the following:

- Increase reliable session inactivity timeout
- Increase recieve time out

If it's still not working, also increase the reliable 'maxRetryCount'.

This helped me out, I hope that is also works for you!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

We get this error if the sessions are not sticky on the load-balancer. For anyone else that has this issue, this would be something to check and make sure it is working correctly.